# Raid 5 array (6 hard disks) degraded and operating system is not loading

Tags: raid

This is an SOS. I have an R720 dell server with a corrupt operating system. The hard drive has an existing Raid 5 array with 6 hard disks (300gb sas firmware e66) prior to this time. I systematically rebuilt one of the hard drive with 300gb sas firmware e62. and replaced another that is blinking amber with 300gb sas firmware e66.

The raid 5 was rebuilt successfully according to Dell Bios and configuration utility. However i notice the Raid 5 array or the drives are not detectable on windows 2008 server instead i got an error message -  \Boot\BCD error ... An error occured while attempting to read boot configuration drives.

Questions Is it safe to mix an hard disk of lower firmware with hard dirves of higher firmware.

Can i update lifecycle controller as it is requesting for update ?

Comment: Just wipe and restore from backup - also take the opportunity to not use R5 this time, it's 2017 after all, and bring all disks up to the same level too while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

> Questions Is it safe to mix an hard disk of lower firmware with hard dirves of higher firmware.

Usually, yes

> Can i update lifecycle controller as it is requesting for update ?

Yes, but it probably won't fix your problem. Also the lifecycle controller will likely update your new disk to the latest firmware

In answer to your not-actually asked question, you're likely out of luck on any of these actually fixing your problem. Your best way forward is to pull out those backups.

That said, I don't necessarily agree with Chopper3's advice on ditching RAID5. RAID10 and RAID6 offer much better resiliency against disk failure, but on a small array and with small fast disks (well, fast for spinning disks anyway) RAID5 can still be a reasonable option.

Comment: @Chopper3 So what alternative are you proposing to Raid 5 to be at the same level ?